# Airflow 2.0 - Could not automatically determine credentials (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have the following code from the example-dags at "https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags":

```
import os
from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import (
    BigQueryCreateEmptyDatasetOperator, BigQueryDeleteDatasetOperator,
)
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID", "project_id")
DATASET_NAME = os.environ.get("GCP_BIGQUERY_DATASET_NAME", "dataset_id")

default_args = {"start_date": days_ago(1)}

with models.DAG( "test_dag" , default_args=default_args , schedule_interval=None , tags=["testing"] ) as dag:

create_dataset = BigQueryCreateEmptyDatasetOperator(
        task_id="create_dataset", dataset_id=DATASET_NAME
    )

    delete_dataset = BigQueryDeleteDatasetOperator(
        task_id="delete_dataset", dataset_id=DATASET_NAME, delete_contents=True
    )

    create_dataset >> delete_dataset
```

I just want to debug my Airflow connection with Google Cloud, creating a dataset and then removing it. I am currently getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_helpers.py", line 186, in _determine_default_project _, project = google.auth.default()
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 321, in default raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE) google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

After getting this message, I tried to set an environment variable with an assigned path and to add it explicit in the code. None of this options worked. The problem is that any path seem to be unreachable **"google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File was not found"**

Comment: You need to provide servicekey.json file and path as below : os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/path/to/file.json"  Di you just give the path without the file ? This should work actually.

Comment: Where is your Airflow running?

Answer (score 1):

In order to omit this error it might be required to properly define Application Default [credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#finding_credentials_automatically), obtaining valid authentication [*identity*](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#principals) that has granted access to a specific resource across Google platform APIs.

In a common Airflow GCP authentication [concept](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#principals), I assume that you can consider, either:

- Propagate environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`
  approaching the path of a valid service account JSON private key file
  in the particular DAG code, as was proposed by @Priya Agarwal:

  ```
  os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/FULLPATH/TO/JSON.key"
  ```

or

- Create a separate Airflow [connection](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#creating_new_airflow_connections) through WEB UI, specifying
  in **Keyfile Path** field the path to the corresponded *.key file for
  the particular service account, defining then connection ID argument
  in DAG operator's parameters, as explained in [this](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#using_a_new_airflow_connection) example.