# Create a google bigquery connection from Airflow UI (Dockerized)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am running an Airflow instance using Docker. I am able to access the Airflow UI using http://localhost:8080/. Also able to execute a sample dag using PythonOperator. Using PythonOperator I am able to query a big query table on GCP environment. The service account key JSON file is added in my docker compose yaml file.

[image]

[image]

This works perfectly.

Now I want to use BigQueryOperator and BigQueryCheckOperator for which I need a connection ID. This connection ID would come from Airflow connections which happens through Airflow UI.

But when I am trying to create a new Google Bigquery connection getting errors. Could anyone please help me to fix this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your docker compose file, can you set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to `/opt/airflow/configs/kairos-aggs-airflow-local-bq-connection.json`? This might be enough to fix your first screenshot.

[Looking at the docs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#creating_new_airflow_connections) and comparing your second screenshot, I think you could try selecting 'Google Cloud Platform' as the connection type and adding a project ID and Scopes to the form.

[The answers to this question may also be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465176/airflow-2-0-could-not-automatically-determine-credentials-google-application).